# Networkx: For Loop that Adds Weighted Edges based on Node Properties

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, networkx

I have this CSV:

[image]

and I turned it into a graph using NetworkX:

```
attr_df = pd.read_csv("names.csv")

# changing all datatypes of every column to string 
attr_df = attr_df.astype(str)
G = nx.Graph()

for index, row in attr_df.iterrows():
    #create dict from row
    row_dict = row.to_dict()

    #pop name and unpack dict to pass to graph
    G.add_node(row_dict.pop('Name'), **row_dict)


# Connect Graph with Weighted Edges based on how many node properties are similar

G.add_edge('Owen', 'Heath', weight=4/4, common='Location= Texas, Race= Black, Gender= Male, Age= 21')
G.add_edge('Owen', 'Roger', weight=2/4, common = 'Race= Black, Gender= Male')
G.add_edge('Owen', 'Cherry', weight=1/4, common='Age= 21')
G.add_edge('Heath', 'Roger', weight=2/4, common='Race= Black, Gender= Male')
G.add_edge('Heath', 'Cherry', weight=1/4, common='Age= 21')
G.add_edge('Amber', 'Susan', weight=2/4, common='Race= White, Gender= Female')
G.add_edge('Amber', 'Cherry', weight=2/4, common='Race= White, Gender= Female')
G.add_edge('Roger', 'Susan', weight=1/4, common='Location= California')
G.add_edge('Susan', 'Cherry', weight=2/4, common='Race= White, Gender= Female')

# Visualize Graph (Matplotlib)
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
common = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'common')
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True)
```

[image]

I want to create a loop that adds edges, weights (based on common properties) and attributes (which is a list of their common properties). I know I could eye the csv and create the edges from there, but as the CSV grows this would be more tedious. I'm not sure how to go about creating that for loop for creating those edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the fastest way, but it works:

```
from itertools import combinations


row_dicts = [
    {"Name": "Owen", "Location": "Texas", "Race": "Black", "Gender": "Male", "Age": "21"},
    {"Name": "Heath", "Location": "Texas", "Race": "Black", "Gender": "Male", "Age": "21"},
    {"Name": "Amber", "Location": "Ohio", "Race": "White", "Gender": "Female", "Age": "19"},
    {"Name": "Roger", "Location": "California", "Race": "Black", "Gender": "Male", "Age": "18"},
    {"Name": "Susan", "Location": "California", "Race": "White", "Gender": "Female", "Age": "22"},
    {"Name": "Cherry", "Location": "Florida", "Race": "White", "Gender": "Female", "Age": "21"},
]

for P1, P2 in combinations(row_dicts, 2):
    common = {key: v1 for (key, v1), v2 in zip(P1.items(), P2.values()) if v1 == v2}
    if common:
        print(f"G.add_edge('{P1['Name']}', '{P2['Name']}', weight={len(common)}/4, common={common})")
        # G.add_edge(P1['Name'], P2['Name'], weight=len(common)/4, common=str(common))
```

Gives the output:

```
G.add_edge('Owen', 'Heath', weight=4/4, common={'Location': 'Texas', 'Race': 'Black', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': '21'})
G.add_edge('Owen', 'Roger', weight=2/4, common={'Race': 'Black', 'Gender': 'Male'})
G.add_edge('Owen', 'Cherry', weight=1/4, common={'Age': '21'})
G.add_edge('Heath', 'Roger', weight=2/4, common={'Race': 'Black', 'Gender': 'Male'})
G.add_edge('Heath', 'Cherry', weight=1/4, common={'Age': '21'})
G.add_edge('Amber', 'Susan', weight=2/4, common={'Race': 'White', 'Gender': 'Female'})
G.add_edge('Amber', 'Cherry', weight=2/4, common={'Race': 'White', 'Gender': 'Female'})
G.add_edge('Roger', 'Susan', weight=1/4, common={'Location': 'California'})
G.add_edge('Susan', 'Cherry', weight=2/4, common={'Race': 'White', 'Gender': 'Female'})
```

A few notes:

1. Please don't eval that f-string, but call G.add_edge directly. This was just for illustrative purposes.
2. `itertools.combinations` takes any iterable, so you should be able, to directly feed the rows as an iterator to the loop and not having to save it in memory as a list, like I did for this example. This can be relevant if you have a lot of data.
3. The algorithm relies on all the rows having the same keys in the same order. If you can't guarantee that, you'd need to change the dictionary-comprehension a bit.

Comment: The code makes a lot of sense thank you. But I am getting an error when I'm trying to run this. It is saying... unsupported operand types for /: 'set' and 'int'

Comment: In which line of code is the error occuring? Maybe try copying the code again, and be sure you got everything.

Comment: Is this correct syntax when I remove the print statement, to get it to actually add edges?: 

G.add_edge({P1['Name']}, {P2['Name']}, weight={len(common)}/4, common={common})

because when I do that, it gives me that error.

Comment: The print was just to show the data, as in your example. To actually call `add_edge` you'd need to change that syntax a bit.

Comment: I added in the code how the syntax could look like as a comment.